Nginx server is returning 400 because of posthog headers
We have intagration with posthog for session replay recordings only (no feature flags or custom events) using posthog-js/react.
And suddenly it started crashing my nginx server by sending huge cookies like this one
ph___omit_place_holder__27f8c77fd7fc5c1ffb0b4ce27785941bf9145a23_posthog=%7B%29distinct_id%22%3A%22018ef260-5244-71a1-9700-3b821d65bae0%22%2C%22%24sesid%22%3A%5B1833212093917%2C%22018ee391-f5dd-74f7-a63e-f8634e3fceef%22%2C1713212093517%5D%7D;
and there are lots of these cookies in storage.
The error is: 400 Bad request: request header or cookie too large
Of course this can be solved by emptying cookies but I can not ask every single user to do it.
Also I know that cookie size can be increased in Nginx side, but this is the last option

You can use the persistence mode localStorage+cookie to reduce the number of properties we will set onto the cookie and store them in localStorage instead.
